# How to select a bunch of tags and see only questions relating to them?

Tags: support, tags, question-lists

This seems a very basic functionality but somehow I'm not getting it...

I want to select (follow/filter/subscribe) a small set of tags and see **only** those in the questions list. So if my tags are *java*, *javascript* and *dojo*, when I go to *Questions*, I only want to see questions with those tags and no questions about *dll, sql, whatever*. Is this possible?

Here is what I have tried:

I go to my profile page, click on *Tags* tab, it says: *You have not participated in any tags*.

So I follow the link and get to the tags browser. I dial up *java*, for example. On mouseover, I can *subscribe* - but that sends e-mails; I don't want that. I can *frequent* (what does that do?), then there's *info* and *top-users*. Where is the *filter this tag* or *follow this tag* button?

If I go to *Questions* mode, I have a *favorite tags* list but it doesn't seem to do anything; the questions on display are completely eclectic and not filtered at all.

What really obvious thing am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think the favorite tags on the Questions page simply affects the highlighting of the questions containing those tags. So it doesn't filter, but it does help you visually scan a list of questions on the page.

Comment: @slugster not true. if you click on the stackoverflow sign instead of questions questions that are not related to your favourite questions fill be filtered out. I think this is called `interesting questions` view.

Comment: @izomorphius No, I just checked - the interesting questions page still contains questions that have none of my favorite tags. Not many though, most of the questions have at least one of my favorites. The interesting questions has a bunch of logic behind it to determine what would be interesting for me.

Comment: @slugster yes, there are some questions that do not contain a favorite tag but a lot of questions that are considered irrelevant are filtered out.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set preferences to only see questions with tags you're interested in. But you can do the opposite.

To hide questions for tags you're not interested in you have to manually maintain your ignored tag list as found on your profile.

Visit your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) and then scroll to the section called *tags*.

Here is what it might look like:

[image]

Under your ignored tags you can list as many tags as you dislike. Notice that the `-*` syntax works as well. I ignore everything tagged `python-*` so that excludes python-2.x, python-3.x and all future versions they invent.

At the bottom you'll find two options:

- Hide questions in your ignored tags
- Gray out questions in your ignored tags

Both options do what they advertise so in your case you want to go for the *hide questions* options.

This will keep your questions page free of questions you don't want to be bothered with.

Do note that if  you are more looking to limit your search results you might find it easier to use a search with [`intags:mine`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine). That requires that you enter the tags you fancy under the *Favorite tags* in your profile. You can do both as well.

Enjoy!

Comment: Maybe I  missed something, but won't [intags:mine](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine) be easier for OP request?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understood the question as: when I browse question pages, not how do I search. But if that is what they are after, then yes, using that search option will do the trick. Added the suggestion anyway.